# Is it possible to apply multiple filter on a single column using ag-grid in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to customize the agSetColumnFilter and add agNumberColumnFilter functionality within it.
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we do not have possibility to combine it.

But this feature will be present in the next version of Ag-Grid.

Feature in ChangeLog: `AG-1873  Allow set filter to be combined with other filters`

**Next Release Target: 24.0.0 (21st Aug 2020)**

PipeLine: https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/

In a few days, it should be available